# PHP Speeding Up MySql Queries

Tags: php, mysql, performance, laravel, laravel-5

**I am using the Laravel PHP Framework.**

Say I have some queries like this:

```
public function order($orderby){
        \DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();

        if($orderby == "level"){
            $clan = Clans::orderBy('level', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('exp', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(100,['id', 'clanid', 'name', 'level', 'exp', 'warwinpercent', 'warswon', 'playercount', 'score']);
        }elseif($orderby == "score"){
            $clan = Clans::orderBy('score', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(100,['id', 'clanid', 'name', 'level', 'exp', 'warwinpercent', 'warswon', 'playercount', 'score']);
        }elseif($orderby == "warwinpercent"){
            $clan = Clans::orderBy('warwinpercent', 'DESC')
            ->where('warswon', '>=', '100')
            ->paginate(100,['id', 'clanid', 'name', 'level', 'exp', 'warwinpercent', 'warswon', 'playercount', 'score']);
        }else
            $clan = Clans::paginate(100,['id', 'clanid', 'name', 'level', 'exp', 'warwinpercent', 'warswon', 'playercount', 'score']);

        \DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();

        return view('clans.index')->with('clan', $clan);
    }
```

These are taking around 10-15 seconds to run.

I have one like this:

```
public function index(){

        $clan = Clans::orderBy('clanid', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(100,['id', 'clanid', 'name', 'level', 'exp', 'warwinpercent', 'warswon', 'playercount', 'score']);

        return view('clans.index')->with('clan', $clan);
    }
```

Which loads almost instantly.

How come the first 3 are taking so much longer than the last one? I added an Index for all the variables I need to search through in my table but it is still taking ages for it to work. Do I need to do anything on the MySql side to make it rebuild the index? I already tried Optimize table and I restart the MySql Service multiple times as well..

If it isn't possible to speed them up then is there a simple way I can show a loading animation to the user while it loads the page?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is the Explain result for the fast query:

```
explain extended select `id`, `clanid`, `name`, `level`, `exp`, `warwinpercent`, `warswon`, `playercount`, `score` from `clans` order by `clanid` asc limit 100 offset 0
```

[image]

Here is the Explain result for the `orderBy level` query.

```
explain extended select `id`, `clanid`, `name`, `level`, `exp`, `warwinpercent`, `warswon`, `playercount`, `score` from `clans` order by `level` desc, `exp` desc limit 100 offset 0
```

[image]

Here is the `SHOW INDEX FROM clans` result.
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I also have this code that searches for a string in the column `name`

```
public function clans(){
        if((isset($_GET['search'])) && $_GET['search'] != ""){

            $search = $_GET['search'];
            $result = Clans::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(100,['id', 'clanid', 'name', 'level', 'exp', 'warwinpercent', 'warswon', 'playercount', 'score']);
            $data = array(
                'result'  => $result,
                'search'   => $search
            );

            return view('search.clans')->with($data);

        }else
            return view('errors.1')->with('message', 'You entered an invalid search term');
    }
```

This again can take seconds to load..

Explain Query:

```
explain extended select `id`, `clanid`, `name`, `level`, `exp`, `warwinpercent`, `warswon`, `playercount`, `score` from `clans` where `name` LIKE '%lol%' limit 100 offset 0
```

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question with the raw queries and the explain plans

Comment: sprinkling poorly chosen indexes can potentially slow things down even more

Comment: @Drew has a good point. Check out this [article](http://ajaxline.com/32-tips-to-speed-up-your-mysql-queries).

Comment: ultimately you Laravel guys can peek at a raw query. So plop the word `explain` in front of it, run that at the console, and publish those results

Comment: @Drew yeah Ik about poor indexing. I indexed my table well. I will update with the explains.

Comment: Since you dont have a WHERE clause no index can be used,you are getting the whole table.One solution is to use some kind of cache, you run that query once a minute or so and deliver the results instantly from cache.Laravel must have something like that.

Comment: @Mihai what if I added a where statement like: `WHERE level > 1` would that help or make no difference?

Comment: In general indexes are useful when you return a small proportion of the rows.Make sure the column used in WHERE is indexed.But if you use a WHERE your pagination goes to s..

Comment: @Mihai So adding a WHERE clause which will still return all the rows won't make a difference?

Comment: @Mihai so there isn't really anyway to speed it up?

Comment: I also would raise an eyebrow toward whether some of the indexes you showed are ever used. I believe you might need less of them, and more composites. But you know the access routes. If you had a composite index on `(level,exp)`, you might drastically reduce the cardinality, and it *may* come back snappy

Comment: What's a composite index? Put it in your answer. By the sounds of it, it might help? :S @Drew

Comment: @Drew the only two that aren't used in the code I gave are name and location. I am updating my post with the code for name as it is a `LIKE` query. Maybe it can be sped up?

Comment: @Drew see my second update.

Comment: my point is this. If you have 10 columns, and you have single column separate indexes (read: not composite indexes) on 7 of them, there is a good chance it is just wishful thinking. The query plan doesn't jump from one index to another mid-stream. It picks one. So have ones that fulfill  the need baked in. A partial use index can go so far then do a where afterwards, but composites that are wisely chosen are used, and don't waste space. So just sprinkling or shotgunning index creations is going to drag down insert/updates, and do nothing if not used in reads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with query 2 (query 1 looks fine). But with two, though you have an index on level, the cardinality is so high that mysql abandons it. Row count 170K, cardinality 159k

From the manual page entitled [How MySQL Uses Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html):

> Indexes are less important for queries on small tables, or big tables
>   where report queries process most or all of the rows. When a query
>   needs to access most of the rows, reading sequentially is faster than
>   working through an index. Sequential reads minimize disk seeks, even
>   if not all the rows are needed for the query. See Section 8.2.1.16,
>   “How to Avoid Full Table Scans” for details.

### Composite Index

A composite ([Multi-column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)) index is an index on 2 or more columns as a combo. Can be unique, or not.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `thing_my_composite` ON thing (position,email,dob); -- forbid dupes hereafter
```

### Covering Index

A covering index is one in which the query can be resolved via a quick stroll through the index b-tree, **without** requiring a lookup into the actual table **data** page. These are the ultimate nirvana for speed. [Percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/) quick article on it.

### Full Text Searches (based on OP comments)

From this manual page on [Full-Text Search Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html), here is an excerpt:

> MySQL has support for full-text indexing and searching:
>
> A full-text index in MySQL is an index of type FULLTEXT.
>
> Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables. (In MySQL 5.6
>   and up, they can also be used with InnoDB tables.) Full-text indexes
>   can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.
>
> A FULLTEXT index definition can be given in the CREATE TABLE statement
>   when a table is created, or added later using ALTER TABLE or CREATE
>   INDEX.
>
> For large data sets, it is much faster to load your data into a table
>   that has no FULLTEXT index and then create the index after that, than
>   to load data into a table that has an existing FULLTEXT index.

Comment: That gave a cardinality of 214! Snappppy!! :) That's solved that one, is there no way to fix the other queries? Which are `order by score desc` and `order by warwinpercent desc`?

Comment: the last update to question with `name like '%frog%'` is going to do a tablescan. To solve, that would require either `mysql full text` searching, or a junction table sorta thing.

Comment: I am on MySql 5.5 and Innodb. Can't use full text :(

Comment: do all your tables need to be in innodb ?

Comment: yeah. A lot more benefits with it

Comment: Upgraded to MySql 5.6 Super fast now :D